# Consulta SQL normalizar acentos, til

Tags: mysql

Tenho que muitas vezes pesquisar nomes de produtos que possuem acentos.. como normalizar isso?

Na minha tabela uso o collation utf8_general_ci, que serve bem para maiúsculas e minúsculas(CI).

Agora, acentos, estão sendo um problema, este collation já ignora algo como, é de e, á de a, o problema é (ã->till) com a,.. o que fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente enviar uma consulta

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Pessoalmente eu resolvi o mesmo problema adicionando depois do **código de conexão MySQL** :

`mysql_set_charset("utf8");`

ou:
`mysqli_set_charset("utf8");`

ou o equivalente em **POO** :
`$mysqli_link->set_charset("utf8");`

E às vezes você terá que definir o **charset principal do php** adicionando este código :
`mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');`

No lado do cliente HTML você tem que adicionar os seguintes dados do cabeçalho :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Para utilizar os resultados JSON AJAX (por exemplo, usando jQuery), você deve definir o cabeçalho adicionando :

```
header("Content-type: application/json;charset=utf8");
json_encode(
     some_data
);
```

Isso deve resolver

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, elas são úteis tanto que eu já havia aplicado elas, o problema então não era esse nem o collation da BD, e sim de como eu realizava a consulta, era atravez de REGEXP, logo Verao e Verão seriam diferentes de fato, ai usei a comparação com igualdade, algo como WHERE x = 'Verao' e retornou registros de Verao e Verão, como eu esperava. Grato pela resposta @RenatoTavares